# grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot, dialogflow

Я делаю бота с разным функционалом включая систему диалогов DialogFLow.
При коде

```
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message and message.reply_to_message.from_user.id == bot.get_me().id)
    def dialog(message):
        senderID = message.from_user.id
        DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'small-talk-rwvf'
        DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
        DIALOGFLOW_SESSION_ID = senderID
        print(1)
    
        dialogflow_session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
        dialogflow_session = dialogflow_session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, DIALOGFLOW_SESSION_ID)
        print(2)
        text_input = dialogflow.TextInput(text=message.text, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
        query_input = dialogflow.QueryInput(text=text_input)
        print(3)
        try:
            response = dialogflow_session_client.detect_intent(session=dialogflow_session, query_input=query_input)
            print(4)
        except InvalidArgument:
            response = None
            print("error")
    
        if response:
            bot.reply_to(message, response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "Извините, я вас не понял.")
```

Я получаю ошибки

```
2023-07-17 13:15:45,613 (__init__.py:962 Thread-1 (bot_polling)) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 65, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 910, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/small-talk-rwvf/agent' denied."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:10.0.0.118:3128 {grpc_message:"IAM permission \'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent\' on \'projects/small-talk-rwvf/agent\' denied.", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2023-07-
17T13:15:45.553896104+00:00"}"
```

и

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 955, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "/home/GLORPC/EVENT_BOT/eventbot.py", line 1779, in dialog
    response = dialogflow_session_client.detect_intent(session=dialogflow_session, query_input=query_input)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/dialogflow_v2/services/sessions/client.py", line 661, in detect_intent
    response = rpc(
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 349, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 191, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/GLORPC/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/small-talk-rwvf/agent' denied.
"
```

Я смотрел похожие вопросы на Stackoverflow, однако не нашел ответа.